# Change language of Toyota HDD Navigation (NHDN-W56) from japanese to english

Tags: toyota, navigation

I have an imported Toyota from japan with Toyota Genuine HDD Navigation and music  system(NHDN-W56). The problem is that the whole thing is in japanese,can anyone help me how to change the language from Japanese to English?
below are the images of it.

[image: The Navigation and audio system]

Anyone who can help, thanks in advance

Comment: What you Model/Year? It may be in someone else user's manual.

Comment: I have read a lot of posts all over the internet where people are having the same issue as you with no resolution to their issue. The *best* suggestion I could find for you is to download an Android app called "Cam Dictionary", then take a picture of the display, which will translate it from Japanese to English for you. Using this method, you should be able to shuffle through the menus to find "settings" and then change the language to English. If this works, post the exact menu selections you used to do this and post it back up here (or create a video and post up a link). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think the firmware  is internationalised. Let's hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi Can anyone please help me to convert NHDN W56 to English, I am willing to pay for the software

Answer (score 1):

I had a long look around and the only solution seems to be a firmware update. You will have to contact the manufacturer of the device for assistance. Luckily the manufacturer is Panasonic, so you have a slightly better than average chance of being helped. Go to [this page](http://panasonic.net/products/cars/) and click on the "consumer Support" link. There's a link to tech support too, but it didn't seem terribly helpful to me.

Comment: Are you sure this is a panasonic? av searched everywhere on there website for this model but got nothing...

Comment: No, I'm not. I found a few websites stating this is a panasonic device. Your problem is probably that this is a japan-only product and so it won't be mentioned in other markets. Best thing to do is to contact Toyota and have them sort it out for you.